# Getting error to connect database after using @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, annotations

Using @Component annotation in Spring Cron, cron is running well, but another configuration is not working, like database connection is not established, loggers are not printing
Getting error while login from the web project

Below is my code

```
@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.ravi","com.ravi.main"})
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringBootApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);       
    }

}
```

And below code is cron

```
@Component
@Lazy(false)
public class CleanDataJob {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CleanDataJob.class);
    @Scheduled
    public void deleteData() {
        // Cleaning data job code       
    }
    
}
```

Cron is added in com.ravi.main package
After deleting @Component all database connections are working fine but, cron is not running

Comment: 1) If the SpringBootApplication is in com.ravi you can delete ComponentScan 2) please show the stacktrace

Comment: 1. If ComponentScan is deleted, getting 404 for web project 
2. Stacktrace is : Jan 11, 2022 4:34:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: Hello Simon
When I remove @ComponentScan from SpringBootApplication getting error stacktrace is below.........
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataCleanJob': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'DataCleanJob'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ravi.DataCleanJob' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate..... Waiting for you reply

Answer (score 0):

Check for @Autowired annotation that is left inside the @Component annotated class